# How to Sync Text Messages from Outlook 2010 to Android

Tags: sms, outlook, samsung-infuse-4g

I went from the HTC "Tilt" running Windows 6.1 to the Samsung INFUSE running Android. I use an exchange server plus Outlook 2010 at my office. I can no longer send/receive text messages from my desktop. Everything else sync's fine. Does Android support an exchange between the PDA and the desktop for text messages?

Answer (score 1):

[SMS Backup +](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.zegoggles.smssync) will sync SMS messages to your GMail account, you can then sync those to your outlook using [Google Apps Sync](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=153866).

Answer (score 0):

No, not directly.

However, if you use Google Voice, you can have all your text messages emailed to you, which would allow you to sync them.

[Link to Google Voice](http://Google.com/voice)

Answer (score 0):

There is a messaging app called [Touchdown](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nitrodesk.droid20.nitroid&hl=en) which will sync SMS. It is not perfect but I'll never go back. You can see more on their [website](http://www.nitrodesk.com/dk_touchdownFeatures.aspx).

Comment: I don't see anything on that page about SMS, nor on their [Android Market](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nitrodesk.droid20.nitroid) page.